# Failed to resolve: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:16.+'

Tags: android

I have a little problem with Android Studio:

> Failed to resolve: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:16.+'

[image: error]

I also tried to install repository but appear another error.

[image: Error2]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "p11zt.futebol24"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    } }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:16.+' }
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: post your Gradle file

Comment: @PavanBilagi check main post.

Comment: 1) Study the difference between compile version, target version and minimum version. 2) Appcompat-v7 r16 does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change compile sdk to 23 try this

```
 compileSdkVersion 23
 targetSdkVersion 23
```

and use support:appcompat

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
```

Comment: ...appcompat-v7:23.1.1. Compile version and support library versions should match.

Comment: Thanks @PavanBilagi!!